# Replace string dynamically using Regex in java code

Tags: regex, dynamic, replaceall

I want solution as below in java code

String inputStr = "This is a sample @hostname1 @host-name2 where I want to convert the string like :@test host-@test1 to format i.e dollar followed by open braces, string and close braces.";

Output String I need as

output: "This is a sample ${hostname1} ${host-name2} where I want to convert the string like :${test} host-${test1} to format i.e dollar followed by open braces, string and close braces.";

I tried below like

```
public void regEx(String intputStr){
        String pattern = "\\S(@)\\S+";
         Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
         Matcher m = r.matcher(commands);

         String replacePattern = " \\$\\{\\S+\\} ";
         int i=0;

         while(m.find()) {
             Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(intputStr).replaceAll(replacePattern);
            // System.out.println(m.group(i));
             //i++;
         }   
        // System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(intputStr);
    }
```

But I get exceptions and not able to proceed. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get away with the following one-liner:

```
inputStr = inputStr.replaceAll("@(.*?)\\s", "\\${$1} ");
```

This matches the regex `@(.*?)\\s`, which captures everything between the at symbol and nearest space, and replaces it with the formatting you want.

```
String inputStr = "This is a sample @hostname1 @host-name2 where I want to convert the string like :@test host-@test1 to format i.e dollar followed by open braces, string and close braces.";
// add space to match term should it occur as the last word
inputStr += " ";
inputStr = inputStr.replaceAll("@(.*?)\\s", "\\${$1} ");
inputStr = inputStr.substring(0, inputStr.length()-1);

System.out.println(inputStr);
```

**Output:**

```
This is a sample ${hostname1} ${host-name2} where I want to convert the string like :${test} host-${test1} to format i.e dollar followed by open braces, string and close braces.
```